# How can I stop Cyber Bullying and prevent this in future for my child?

Tags: discipline, daycare

Actually I am afraid of using Facebook and other social networking sites as it fears me of Cyber bullying. Many tried to make my friends reputation down and by this I am also getting afraid of using it. I really think why people do this and how to stop these things and I also checked so many site's to how to stop it but I didn't find any good solution. As I want to be sure and wanted to know more about these things and I don't want this thing to be happen to us in future.

So is there any solution or any website where I can go and complain or any suggestion like what we have to do in these situations as I know at these situations person suffer a lot and I know Cyber bullying is illegal too so I just want some solution to how to prevent these things.